# check in javascript if call is being made from a particular jsp

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file global.js which is a common js file.

I have added few lines of code in function named test this javascript file.

The problem is I want these lines of code to be executed only when call is being made from a particular jsp named home.jsp and not any other jsp.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: NOTE: jsp in the URL is different from the jsp that i want to check

Answer (score 0):

You can check Page Name as

```
var PagePath = window.location.pathname;
var PageName = PagePath.substring(PagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if(PageName == "YourDesiredPage")
{
        // Execute particular lines of code here
        // Do Whatever you want
}
```

Comment: @sweta yes pathname is the URL

Comment: Problem is that jsp that i want to check is a lightbox. URL in the address bar is of the parent jsp

Answer (score 0):

An obvious solution is to get those lines out of that file, and include it separately. This is the recommended one.

Another possibility is to check `location` and execute conditionally.

Yet another, define some variable before the script tag; or use [this technique](http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html) to pass it in the script URL.